# Why do C++ smart pointer implementations keep the reference counter on the heap together with the pointee?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, boost, smart-pointers, c++-loki

Reading Alexandrescu and wikipipidia I see the pointee and the reference counter are stored on the heap. Then there is mention that reference counting is inefficient as counter must be allocated on the heap? Why isn't it stored on the stack?

Comment: Can you show an example of what you are describing?

Comment: Both "reference counter" and "heap" are mere implementation details. The real beef is that shared ownership semantics can only be implemented with dynamic allocation.

Answer (score 9):

Because you would lose it as soon as the current instance of the smart pointer goes out of scope.

A smart pointer is used to simulate automatic storage objects that were allocated dynamically. The smart pointers themselves are managed automatically. So when one is destroyed, anything it stores in automatic storage is also destroyed. But you don't want to lose the reference counter. So you store it in dynamic storage.

Answer (score 3):

It can't be stored on the stack because then a copy of the object would also result in a copy of the refcount, which would defeat its purpose.

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, the stack isn't an appropriate place to keep the reference count because the object may outlive the current stack frame (in which case the reference count would go away!)

It's worth noting that some of the inefficiencies associated with putting the reference count on the heap can be overcome by storing it "together" with the object itself.  In boost, this can be accomplished by using [boost::make_shared](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/smart_ptr/make_shared.html) (for shared_ptr's) or [boost::intrusive_ptr](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/smart_ptr/intrusive_ptr.html).

Answer (score 1):

There are different types of smart pointers, designed for different purposes. The pointer you are talking about is a **shared smart pointer** (`std::shared_ptr`), which helps sharing object ownership from multiple places. All the copies of `shared_ptr` increment and decrement the same counter variable, which is placed on the heap, as it needs to be available to all copies of the `shared_ptr` even after the first copy dies.

So, `shared_ptr` internally keeps two pointers: to the object and to the counter. Pseudocode:

```
class SharedPointer<T> {
public:
// ...
private:
    T* obj;
    int* counter;
}
```

By the way, when you create object with `std::make_shared`, the implementation may optimize allocations by allocating enough memory to hold both the counter and the object and then constructing them side-by-side.

This trick at its extreme gives us an intrusive reference counting pattern: the object internally holds its counter and provides `AddRef` and `Release` functions to increment and decrement it. The you can use **intrusive smart pointer**, e.g. `boost::intrusive_ptr`, which uses this machinery and thus doesn't need to allocate another separate counter. This is faster in terms of allocations, but requires to inject the counter to the controlled class definition.

Also, when you don't need sharing object ownership and only need to control it's lifetime (so that is gets destructed when function returns), you can use the **scoped smart pointer**: `std::unique_ptr` or `boost::scoped_ptr`. It doesn't need the counter altogether, as only one copy of the `unique_ptr` exists.